# Is it possible to create a custom cursor using PyQt?

Tags: python, image, pyqt, qcursor

I wanted to use a bigger version of the crosshair cursor for my program but it seems like i can't change the specs of the standard cursor shapes (e.g. QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor). That said, is it possible for me to create a customized version of a cursor instead? Like say, from a png image of a cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The image should be opened first using PIL, converted to bitmap and then instantiated as a cursor.</s>
<s>here's the code:</s>

```
 from PIL import Image
    from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
    img = Image.open('cursor.png')
    imgQ = ImageQt(img)
    cursorBitmap = QtGui.QBitmap.fromImage(imgQ)
    CURSOR_NEW = QtGui.QCursor(cursorBitmap)
```

edit: as @ekhumoro pointed out in the comments, it can be achieved by [using Pixmap and combining it with QCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qcursor.html#QCursor-3), so it'd look like:

```
CURSOR_NEW = QtGui.QCursor(QtGui.QPixmap('cursor.png'))
```

if this causes an error it might be because the code cannot find the correct file, so the proper path might need to be added to the code

Comment: What's the point of all that PIL cruft? All [that's required](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qcursor.html#QCursor-3) is `QCursor(QPixmap('cursor.png'))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro i tried this at first and the app kept crashing. turns out it's looking for the image in a different directory and the full path is needed in order to locate the image correctly